SwiftData not updating after adding new element
I have a Workout that has an inverse RelationShip with Exercise:
@Model
class Workout: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Exercise.workout) //when deleting a workout you delete all exericses that happened during that workout
    var exercises: [Exercise]?

@Model
class Exercise: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var exerciseName: ExerciseName
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \MySet.exercise)
    var sets: [MySet]?    //When an Exercise gets Deleted all Sets associated need to get deleted

    var date: Date
    var workout: Workout

Then In another view I pass a workout and create a new set with that workout as a  Parent:
Button {
                if(selection != nil) {
             
                    let newExercise = Exercise(id: UUID(),exerciseName: selection!, date: workout.endTime, workout: workout)
    
                     modelContext.insert(newExercise)
                    
                    let set =  MySet(id: UUID(), weight: 0, reps: 0,isCompleted: false,date: Date.now ,exercise: newExercise)

                     modelContext.insert(set)
                 
                    dismiss()
                }
                
            } 

this shows up straight away on the editworkoutview but when I go back to my workout list view I need to refresh the app to see the number of exercises a workout has. that view queries workouts and then I use its exercises to see the number of exericses that workout has:
    @Query(animation: .easeIn) var workouts: [Workout]

 ForEach(workouts) { workout in
                    NavigationLink(value: workout) {

if let exercises =  workout.exercises {
                                    Text("\(exercises.count)x Exercises")
                                        .font(.system(size: 13))
                                }

The Text only displays the correct amount of exercises when I refresh the app.

Note, @Model class ... already conforms to Identifiable,
there is no need to add your own id and Identifiable

Try explicitly calling .save() on the context and see if any errors are caught.

A remedy is to run a query on the child data object and filter it using a computed property to get a nice list of all of workouts children like so:
private func countExercises(for workout: Workout) -> Int {
    // Filter the exercises to get those related to the current workout
    let filteredExercises = exercises.filter { $0.workout == workout }
    return filteredExercises.count
}

 Text("\(countExercises(for: workout))x Exercises")                                                                         

